# Java method that accepts references to interface objects

Tags: java, methods, interface

I'm kinda unsure about the following question:

If `Launchable` is a Java interface, what objects can be passed into the following method? What methods could be invoked on item inside this method?

```
public void prepareForLaunch (Launchable item) {
    // some code
}
```

My current answer is:
From the above information, the only objects that can be passed into the method are objects that where instantiated as subclass types of the interface `Launchable`.(?) The methods that could be invoked on item inside the method would have to be public methods or protected methods within the same package. These methods would also have to be to be intended for a subclass of `Launchable` object since it is only in abstract and actual(concrete) classes where a method body’s definition can exist.

I was wondering if someone here can check my answer and add any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass in instances of classes that implement `Launchable` (either directly, or by inheritance from a superclass). You can also pass in `null`.

Inside of the method, you can call all the methods defined in `Launchable` (and in `Object`).

These methods would be *defined* in the `Launchable` interface, but *implemented* in the actual class (a fact that is guaranteed by the Java type system, which won't let you have classes with incomplete interface implementations, those would need to be declared abstract and cannot be instantiated).

If you need to call any other methods you need to know that the object in question also implements some other interface (or is of a given class), and do a typecast to that first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that `Launchable` is an interface, an instance of any class that implements `Launchable` could be passed to `prepareForLaunch`. Any class implementing `Launchable` would have to implement the methods defined in the interface and thus any method of `Launchable`could be invoked to objects given to `prepareForLaunch`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the first part. About the methods you can invoke: If you are not using casting then you can only invoke public\protected within the same package of Launchable. If you will use casting you can extend the range of the methods you can invoke to the methods in the casted-to class.

Consider this code:

```
public interface Launchable
{
    public void aMethod();
}
public class SomeClass implements Launchable
{
    public void aMethod()
    {
    }
    public void bMethod(){}
}
```

Without casting youll be able to call

```
item.aMethod();
```

With Casting youll be able to call:

```
((SomeClass)item).bMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use `implements` statement ,

```
public void prepareForLaunch() implements Launchbla {
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid statement. A class can implement an interface, but a method can't.

Comment: its ok ,and you can use all the methods thats defined into the interface!

Comment: I'm sorry but you are wrong, that line will not compile in Java.